# Uploading data from database through php

Tags: php, jquery

The problem is uploading announcements as a div element. I looked for a way to do this through jQuery however I have very little knowledge in jQuery so I couldn't find a solution. I did find a solution through PHP which works, however it's not very elegant and I feel there is a better way to do this.

Here is the code (announcements.php):

```
<?php
$sql = $link->prepare('SELECT content, dateset FROM announcements WHERE email=":email"');
$sql->bindParam(':email', $_SESSION['email']);
$sql->execute();
$row = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($row as $r) {
    echo '<div class="announcement"><div class="announcementTopBar"><div class="announcementPic"><img src="smiley.png" alt="pic" width="25" height="25" /></div><span>Some Dude</span></div><div id="announcementContent"><span>';
    foreach ($r as $data) {
        echo $data;
    }
    echo '</span></div></div>';
}
?>
```

HTML file:

```
<div id="somediv">
    <?php include("announcements.php"); ?>
</div>
```

Is there any other method I can use? Is this solution (with some refining) sufficient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your solution. The other alternative is to use an [AJAX call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) to retrieve the data, and use Javascript to append it to the DOM.

**Reasons to use PHP:**

- Not all browsers support Javascript, and you can turn Javascript off
- Consistent output of your data at all times

**Reasons to use AJAX:**

- If you want new data to be added to your page without having to refresh the page. E.g.:

  - A "click here to load" button loading the content without refreshing the page
  - Automatically adding new content to a page at intervals (like Facebook's news feed)
  - Removing or editing data in the same way

**Note:** the only error I can see in your code is that you're defining an element with the ID `announcementContent` within your loop - HTML specs only allow one instance of an ID in the DOM. You should use a class here instead which are meant to be used for (potentially) multiple instances of an element.

Comment: So if I were to use an AJAX call, I would have to append from a specific div every time. How would I make it do that?

Answer (score 0):

I can see here that you are creating nested  tags with specific classes,  tag and displaying data between them. This can be achieved through jquery also by creating tags , adding classes to them and appending it to their respective parent into the hierarchy.

```
var x =  $("<div></div>").addClass("className");

$("#parentDiv").append(x);
```

For getting the data from the server AJAX Call is always a better option which is an Async call (can be changed).

For AJAX call read here [POST AJAX REQUEST](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: I disagree with your comment on suitability. Also your jquery is misleading, the selector and the text content are very different things

Comment: $("<div>Text</div>").addClass("className"); it is....I am adding the <div> tag inside the selector but i don't know why I cannot see it..

Comment: @scrowler And please explain the suitability point here. Any better option to get the data from the database.??

Comment: Edited your code display for you - code should be indented with four spaces rather than quote lines which are `>`. Your comment regarding suitability for database retrieval - there is nothing more suitable than getting data straight from a database and displaying is with a server side language. Ajax shouldn't be used where it's not necessary.